# overflow-x: hidden; hide the left, not the right?

Tags: css

when I overflow-x; hidden my table inside a max-width container, it hides the overflowing content on the right. but it would like it to hide whats on the right instead. in my example, some of text "(should be hidden)" would be hidden, and you would see the "short text"s

i've tried 
`direction: rtl`
and
`position: absolute; right: 0`
without luck

```html
<div class="box">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>howdy partner</td>
      <td><i>short text</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>(should be hidden) how partner howdy partner</td>
      <td><i>short text</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>howdy partner</td>
      <td><i>short text</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>howdy partner</td>
      <td><i>short text</i></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table {
  background-color: #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wry7bsdf/1/

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add flex and direction as row-reverse

```
    .box {
     background-color: #eee;
     padding: 20px;
     margin: 10px;
     max-width: 300px;
     text-align: right;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
```